# Xamarin Forms Entry throwing Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms' `Entry` to retrieve some data when then `OnTextChanged` event is called.

Sometimes, it will throw an uncatchable `Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which crashes the application.

The code I used is:

```
private void textbox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     TextChanged();
}

public async void TextChanged()
{
     try
     {
         if(textbox.Text.Length > 5) //< This sucks and I know it. 
         {
             string text = textbox.Text;
             await Task.Run(()=>doSomeMadlyDemandingRandomStuff(text));
         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         //Bloody exception is never caught.
     }
}
```

I am aware that the conditional at `TextChanged()` is lightyears away from being  performatic, but at this point, I just want it to work.

The aforementioned exception is thrown when the user types a rather long sentence, or when he backspaces a few times.

The entire exception is `Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20`.

**Remarks**

1) I tried to run `Environment.StackTrace`, but it freezes and I just don't know where it is thrown. Any helps regarding this would be appreciated.

2) It used to throw this very exception when the total length was larger than 20 characters and the `await`ed method received the `Text` property directly which, I suspect, mangled with the values out of the running Thread. Passing a variable (`text`) solved *that* problem.

3) I know what the `Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means. I just don't know **when** it is accessing an index that is out of bounds.

4) Xamarin Forms' `Editor` has the same issue.

5) Some context to clarify what this textbox is supposed to do: It is supposed to serve as an autocomplete(able) entry, where the user types a few letters, a listview is populated with  results, and keeps being updated as the remaining letters are typed.

Comment: try catch(Exception )
     {
     }

Comment: Funny that it catches the exception if no variable is provided, but sadly I can't just ignore this issue.

Comment: check doSomeMadlyDemandingRandomStuff implementation.

Comment: It uses the string provided to send it via `DependencyService` to an Android-based component. Shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Never mind it. Catching the exception with no variable did not catch it at all.

Comment: Try adding a `try`/`catch` within the `Task.Run`? I thought I read that exceptions do not make it out of that, though I also thought I read that they would be swallowed as well. Maybe since it is happening in the Android code, they are not being swallowed?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Thanks for the advice. I really forgot about that behavior. Still not catching this bloody exception, though :(

Comment: Dang, maybe try adding the following to your `MainActivity`? `AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += StoreLogger;` ([link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/183976/#Comment_183976))

Comment: I already override this event, @hvaughan3, and _sometimes_ it falls within it. _Continuing_ still crashes the app though :(

Comment: Right it would not prevent a crash but might tell you where it is crashing if you can follow the stack trace or view the fragments buried within the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I see potential problems with `doSomeMadlyDemandingRandomStuff`... if this is going to take a while, what is to stop the user from changing the text again and thus calling the handler again before you are done with handling the first text changed event? As a test, you might want to temporarily disable the text box until the "MadlyDemandingRandomStuff" is done to see if this handler being called again before the first handler completes might be a proximate cause of the issue, e.g.:

```
public async void TextChanged()
{
    textbox.IsEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        if(textbox.Text.Length > 5) //< This sucks and I know it. 
        {
            string text = textbox.Text;
            await Task.Run(()=>doSomeMadlyDemandingRandomStuff(text));
            textbox.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
     //Bloody exception is never caught.
    }
}
```

I know this may not be an "answer" but it may help find the issue, so posting it as such.

Also if this is a native exception, sometimes native exceptions cause the app to crash before any exception can be sent back to the managed side, thus your catch block will never catch it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @jgoldberger. I updated the question to provide some context into what the textbox is supposed to do. The user is _encouraged_ to keep typing and, if I disable the component, the Android's keyboard is "pushed back".

Comment: @EricWu I created my own autocomplete page that fills a `ListView` as the user types (it calls a service for the data) and I added a throttle `TimeSpan` which may work similar to disabling the text box without having the user see the effect. Adding something like the following to your `Task.Run`: `if(DateTime.UtcNow - _lastRequestDateTime <= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)) { return; } _lastRequestDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;`

Comment: @hvaughan3 that actually sounds plausible, but seems a little ... ugly. I'm going to try it out and, if it works, I'll let you know.